# How to restrict page number options in Bootstrap 4 DataTables pagination

Tags: javascript, datatables, pagination

I want to restrict page number options in the Bootstrap Data Tables Pagination option.

Currently, it's showing like this:

[image]

But I want to show it like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$.fn.DataTable.ext.pager.numbers_length = 5;` where `5` is number of displayed buttons (next, prev, 1,2 and 3)

live example [link](http://live.datatables.net/sukaxabe/2645/edit)

Comment: Worth mentioning: In addition to this answer, you can do further customizations - see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39642041/12567365) which shows how to hide buttons displaying ellipses.